# Docusign Request the authorization code without open a browser

Tags: docusignapi, abap

I'm developing a solution in ABAP and I need to request the authorization code without opening a browser.

I need this code to call API but I don't know how to recover it without opening a browser.

hope your help
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you wrote "authorization code", I would imagine what you really need/care about is the access token to make API calls.

You would be able to use JWT to get it without a browser - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

However there's a one-time consent required (with impersonation scope) that would just be you doing it once (or the admin of the account you will let use your app) and that is a one time thing only.
After that using JWT you can make API calls (after you get access tokens) without opening a browser.